# why this lambda expression do not work when in statement ,but work in method?

Tags: java, lambda, stream

the propose i wanted is filter a list by some inner object's field.
thus i find one method in internet ,like this :

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

then ,i use like this

```
list.stream().filter(LambdaUtils.distinctByKey(o -> o.getLogisticsNumber() == null ? o.getId() : o.getLogisticsNumber())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

it works correct ,but i want try something different ,so i change the code not use a function but instead of code .like this:

```
list.stream().filter(
                    x -> {
                        Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
                        Function<DeliveryOrderItemMaterialLogisticInfo ,Object> keyExtractor = o -> o.getLogisticsNumber() == null ? o.getId() : o.getLogisticsNumber();
                        return seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(x), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
                    }
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then the result is error.

why ? what different between those two?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You should add the error message; in any case, your last version of the code is useless since it creates a new Map every time it filters one item. In the first snippet, only one map is created and the same map is used for every filtered element. Note that with this type of stateful lambda, you cannot use parallel streams as it would create data race conditions.

Comment: i'm sorry ,it's not error ,it's wrong with the result. the result does not filter the distinct record .

Comment: i have got the point why it does not work ,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second code version:

```
Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

The map `Map<> seen` is initialized for every element `x`, therefore your filter always return `true` which will let all elements passthrough.

Move the `Map<> seen` declaration to outside the lambda will correct your usage.

In the first code version, the `Map<> seen` is only initialized one. What it returns is just a predicate:

```
return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
```

When you pass this predicate to your stream, it does not create a new `Map` but uses the reference `Map<> seen` declared before.

Comment: yes ,thanks! i study lambda only with simple demo ever. now i get new understanding. the function execute only one time when call filter() but the return lambda statement execute when call collect() every list item .i change `Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();` outside the lambda statement ,then it works correctly. thank you very much!!!